# Find the isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $H=\langle (3^9, 3^2, 3^7) \rangle$.
The factor group $G:=\frac{\mathbb{Z}_{3^{12}} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3^{11}}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3^{10}}}{\langle (3^9, 3^2, 3^7) \rangle}$ is isomorphic to
$\mathbb{Z}_{3^{12}} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3^{2}}\times \mathbb{Z}_{3^{10}}$ which is generated by
$\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$. I want to find an isomorphism between these two groups. What I tried is the following:

The order of $\chi_1=(1,0,0)+H $ is $3^{12}$ and order of $\chi_3=(0,0,1)+H $ is $3^{10}$. But order of $(0,1,0)+H$ is not $3^2$.

If we find an element of  order $3^2$, say $\chi_2$ such that, any element $(a,b,c)+H$, say of $G$ can be generated by $\chi_1, \chi_2, \chi_3$, then the mapping $f$ defined by
$$f(\chi_1)=(1,0,0), f(\chi_2)=(0,1,0), f(\chi_3)=(0,0,1) $$
is an isomorphism.

However, I could not manage to find an appropriate $\chi_2$. Although I found element of order $3^2$, for example, $(0,3^9, 0)+H$ which is of order $3^2$, but this cannot be taken as $\chi_2$. because if not, then there should be integers $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3  $ such that
$$(a-\lambda_1,  b-\lambda_2 3^9, c-\lambda_3 )=m(3^9, 3^2, 3^7)$$
for some integer $m$. But this leads to the following system of linear congruences
\begin{align}
a&\equiv \lambda_1[3^9]\\
b&\equiv \lambda_2 3^9[3^2]\\
c&\equiv \lambda_3[3^7] 
\end{align}
which might not be true always.

What should I do? Any help will be appreciated.

**Update1** I have made a mistake. The element $(0,3^9,0)+ H$ is actually $H$ itself, hence order is not $3^2$ but 1. However, I am still stuck in my old situation, how to find the desired generating element of order $3^2$.

Comment: The Smith Normal Form algorithm not only produces the elementary divisors but also the matrix which transform the original gen set to the new one, so in principle this is trivial. Does it really matter what the answer is? I'd guess $e_2-3^5 e_1-3^7 e_3$ is the element of order $3^2$ but am too lazy to check carefully.

Comment: What are $e1, e2, e3$ ?

Comment: Sorry, the canonical basis: $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$